# Error:404 page not found, code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

controller.php

```
<?php

    define('_root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    include(_root.'/innoshop/application/models/model.php');

     // include_once 'model.php';

    class Controller {
     public $model;

     public function __construct()  
        {  
            $this->model = new Model();

        }
```

If i put localhost:8888/projectname, i got error like this

```
 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

anyone help me

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: is the port 8888 correct?. can you open localhost:8888 ?

Comment: Not sure why you are doing it that way, have you looked into creating a core file in application / core and then MY_Model.php

Comment: I think you should have a better look at codeigniter's documentation. You are not using it as it should be. 
Your Controller must extend CI_Controller and contain an index() function. 
This is also not the good way to load a model.
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

As the guys say you should read the docs as this is very wrong. To fix do this..

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller{//better to give your controller a more meaningful name

       public function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();
           //use the CI loader - the model will then be available like this $this->model->some_function();
           $this->load->model('model');//better to give your model a more meaningful name as well 
       }

       //the index method allows you to use just the controller name in your URI eg localhost:8888/projectname/index.php/controller 
       public function index(){
           echo 'something to see';
       }

        //an alternative controller method get it like localhost:8888/projectname/index.php/controller/your_method_name
        public function your_method_name(){
           echo 'something to see in your method';
        }

}
```

If you want rid of the index.php in the URI search for questions related to .htaccess in CodeIgniter

If you want to be able to use a uri like this `localhost:8888/projectname`  then you need to add a route in config/routes.php that defines the default controller like this `$route['default']='controller';`